# Get filepointer position while reading data from an ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, objectinputstream, randomaccessfile, file-pointer

I need to get the current filepointer-position (in bytes) when I read from my binary file.
I wrote the file using `ObjectOutputStream`, and now I need to read it and remember the byte-position of each object.

However: `ObjectInputStream` doesn't provide a method to read the pointer position, and `RandomAccessFile` cannot read Objects :(

---

If you think there's a way, or even a workaround, this extra information might help:

I have stored IDs in my file. Each ID lists at least one node (can be many nodes).
All as Long-Values.

For Example:

```
ID Node Node ...
123151824812  12419512 1248129412 124912 5992039 1924823590
5238952323942 283492384 234892348 234908234 2348902348 5902303 239235523
...
```

Each ID is an individual object which stores the id-value itself as a long value, the nodes as an `ArrayList<Long>`.

There's a second file which stores Nodes and lists the parenting IDs of each Node.
Like this:

```
Node ID ID ...
12419512 123151824812
234892348 5238952323942 27834918128911
...
```

The idea behind is:
Whenever I know an ID and want to know information about the node, then I look which node is at the specific position in the node-file.
Whenever I know the node and want to know more about its parenting ID, then I look at the specific position in the ID file.

However currently I did just write the ID and Node-values itself into the files using them as "index".

I don't want to look line-for-line if that's the ID I'm looking for, as these files can become very large (GB-size).
It would be easier if I remember the byte-position of the other file instead of a line-index or so, because then I can simply jump to it using skip() or similar methods.

---

Conclusion:  How to get the file pointer position (in bytes) from the beginning of the next object while reading from an `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: How about calculate the number of bytes that 1 object takes and use the `skipBytes` ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)) method to skip the `size*no of objects` bytes.

Comment: The problem is that one Object's size is dynamic. I cannot tell if there is just one node or many nodes and that makes each object different sized :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this, but typically you would create your ObjectInputStream like this

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
```

From the `FileInputStream`, you can call `getChannel()` which returns a `FileChannel`. On the `FileChannel` there is a method `position()` which returns the current file position.

I would think as long as you have not buffering input stream in between, `position()` should return the right value.

Comment: You deserve a cookie!!!  Thanks so much it works fine...  except the skip()-method doesn't skip anything for some reason?! ... However that was not the question and I will look for a solution for this other problem :D